# What are the DAC endpoints for Australia datacenters?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to use the Azure SQL Service Management REST API to [Export Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn781282.aspx). Unfortunately the above documentation does not list any of the Australian Region servers. Does anyone know if what the uriBase values are or if they are even supported in the Australia region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try these:

Australia East: https://aueprod-dacsvc.azure.com/dacwebservice.svc

Australia Southeast:  https://auseprod-dacsvc.azure.com/dacwebservice.svc