# What are the DAC endpoints for the Azure UK Datacentres?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Similar to the question below, but for the UK datacentres, any idea?

[What are the DAC endpoints for Australia datacenters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534062/what-are-the-dac-endpoints-for-australia-datacenters)

Comment: Do take a look at the accepted answer here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c61b4cea-994b-4353-8a44-7963c11c36e2/what-are-the-dac-endpoints-for-the-brazil-and-japan-data-centers?forum=ssdsgetstarted.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had already tried that (probs should have said in question), and got nothing useful. I cross referenced a north europe db that I already know the DAC endpoint for and nothing useful came of that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this question may be old, I had the same issue recently. Luckily, we have Azure Support contract and were able to log a support request with this query.  According to the support engineer, the URLs are:

UK South - https://ukso1prod-dacsvc.azure.com/dacwebservice.svc

UK West - https://ukwe1prod-dacsvc.azure.com/dacwebservice.svc